# SailsJS manually populate records using Model.query

Tags: sql, node.js, sails.js, waterline

lets say i have this example as my app
http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/ORM/Associations/OnetoMany.html

For some big reasons(complicated) I cannot use Model.populate() and I'm stuck in using Model.query()

Does anyone know how to get the result as `User.find().populate('pets')` Using `Model.query()` Please

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like waterline adapters do to populate OneToMany:

1. Retrieve parents :
    `select * from user ...`
2. Retrieve children for each parent in only one query to not overload DBMS:
   `select * from pet where user = user1.id union select * from
   pet where user = user2.id union ...  union select * from pet where user
   = userN.id`.
3. Regroup children by parentPk(you can use lodash or underscore.js functions to do it) Ex:

   `users.forEach(function(user){ 
        user.pets = _.filter(pets,function(pet){
            return pet.user === user.id;
        });
   });`

Comment: Hey Could you please refer this code to the example http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/ORM/Associations/OnetoMany.html .. I have no idea what all the above code means. Sorry

Comment: 1.You should to execute.query to retrieve users you want,2. then you should build a query like the example above to retrieve all pets in a one only query, finally, with 3., you can assign children to their correct parents.